# How to create a subscriber with PubSub on Google Cloud App Engine that listens to a message via Publisher from a Google Cloud App Engine Flex?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Django Application running on Google App Engine. There is another time consuming application running in Google App Engine Flex that is triggered from the Google App Engine Application.

When the Google App Engine Flex Application finished its execution, I want it to trigger a message and send it to Google App Engine Django Application, so Django can update the database item accordingly.

How can I use Google Cloud PubSub to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.[Create a pubsub topic](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#pubsub-create-topic-python)

2.App Engine Flex Application will [publish messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher) to the topic you created

3.Google App Engine Django Application will receive this messages ([receiving messages using pull subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) or  [receiving messages using push subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push)